# bash script to replace all occurrences of placeholders in file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to write a bash script to replace all occurrences of a placeholder in a file with an environment variable of the same name. As an example, if I have a file like the following...

```
This is an {{VAR1}} {{VAR2}}.
It should work across multiple lines in this {{VAR2}}.
```

... and I have the following environment variables set:

```
VAR1='example'
VAR2='file'
```

after running the script on my file, I should get the output:

```
This is an example file.
It should work across multiple lines in this file.
```

I'm sure there must be a solution using awk/sed, but so far the closest I've come can't handle if there's more than one variable on a line. Here's my attempt so far:

```
cat example.txt | grep -o '{{.*}}' > temp
while read placeholder; do
  varName=$(echo "$placeholder" | tr -d '{}')
  value="${!varName}"
  sed -i "s/$placeholder/$value/g" "$file"
done < temp
rm -rf temp
```

Comment: Have you considered using `m4` macro processor?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've not heard of m4 but I'll check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/{{(.*?)}}/$ENV{$1}/g' filename
```

This assumes that `VAR1` and `VAR2` are environment variables (i.e., are `export`ed), so that Perl can pick them out of its environment. This would be required of any approach that isn't pure shell; I just mention it to avoid confusion.

This works as follows:

- `s/pattern/replacement/g` is a substitution command; you may recognize it from sed. The difference is that here we can use Perl's more powerful regex engine and variables. The `g` flag makes it so that all matches are replaced; without it, it would apply only to the first.
- In the pattern, `.*?` matches non-greedily, so that in a line that contains `foo {{VAR1}} bar {{VAR2}} baz`, the pattern `{{.*?}}` matches only `{{VAR1}}` instead of `{{VAR1}} bar {{VAR2}}`.
- The part between `{{` and `}}` is captured because it is between `()` and can be reused as `$1`
- `$ENV{$1}` in the replacement uses the special `%ENV` hash that contains the environment of the Perl process. `$ENV{$1}` is the value of the environment variable that has the name `$1`, which is the captured group from before.

Comment: Make sure you `export VAR1 VAR2` in your script before running this or it will not work.

Answer (score 3):

Only `bash` and `sed`:

```
$ VAR1='example'
$ VAR2='file'
$ export VAR1 VAR2

$ sed -e '{s/{{\([^{]*\)}}/${\1}/g; s/^/echo "/; s/$/";/}' -e e filename
This is an example file.
It should work across multiple lines in this file.
```

- `sed -e '{s/{{\([^{]*\)}}/${\1}/g;}' filename`:

  ```
  This is an ${VAR1} ${VAR2}.
  It should work across multiple lines in this ${VAR2}.
  ```

  - `{{\([^{]*\)}}` - Search for `{{..}}`
  - `[^{]` - Non greedy match
  - `\1` - Access to the bracketed values `\(...\)`.
- `sed -e '{s/{{\([^{]*\)}}/${\1}/g; s/^/echo "/; s/$/";/}' filename`:

  ```
  echo "This is an ${VAR1} ${VAR2}.";
  echo "It should work across multiple lines in this ${VAR2}.";
  ```

  - `s/^/echo "/` - Replace the beginning of the line with `echo "`
  - `s/$/";/` - Replace the end of the line with `";`

Answer (score 1):

I was just playing with your original approach. Wouldn't adding another loop on `$varName` work?

```
cat example.txt | grep -o '{{.*}}' > temp
while read placeholder; do
    varName=$(echo "$placeholder" | tr -d '{}')
    for i in $varName; do
        value="${!i}"
        sed -i "s/{{$i}}/$value/g" example.txt
    done
done < temp
rm -rf temp
```